# One PeerConnection join two AudioSource generated by a different PeerConnectionFactory

Tags: android, audio, webrtc

I have a WebRTC Android app. Can I have a PeerConnection join two AudioSource generated by a different PeerConnectionFactory?

I created two PeerConnectionFactory, one is pcf and the other is micPcf, and used pcf to generate a PeerConnection named pc. Then I added the AudioTrack generated by pcf and micPcf to pc. The remote peer received two AudioTracks, but both are pcf sounds, and there is no micPcf microphone sound, so I would like to ask if a PeerConnection can be added to the AudioSource generated by different PeerConnectionFactory?
If not, is there any way I can make a PeerConnection transmit two types of audio at the same time?

```
val pcf = PeerConnectionFactory.builder().apply {
    val videoEncoderFactory = DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase?.eglBaseContext, true, true)
    val videoDecoderFactory = DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase?.eglBaseContext)
    val adm = JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder(applicationContext)
        .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.REMOTE_SUBMIX)
        .createAudioDeviceModule()

    setVideoEncoderFactory(videoEncoderFactory)
    setVideoDecoderFactory(videoDecoderFactory)
    setAudioDeviceModule(adm)
}.createPeerConnectionFactory()

val micPcf = PeerConnectionFactory.builder().apply {
    val adm = JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder(applicationContext)
        .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        .createAudioDeviceModule()

    setAudioDeviceModule(adm)
}.createPeerConnectionFactory()

val pc = pcf.createPeerConnection(...)


val audioSource1 = pcf.createAudioSource(MediaConstraints())
val audioTrack1 = pcf.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0", audioSource1)
pc.addTrack(audioTrack1, listOf("ARDAMS1"))

val audioSource2 = micPcf.createAudioSource(MediaConstraints())
val audioTrack2 = micPcf.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa1", audioSource2)
pc.addTrack(audioTrack2, listOf("ARDAMS2"))
```